# Как сделать так, чтобы переходить между страницами без перезагрузки, но так чтобы url страницы менялся?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

Как сделать так, чтобы переходить между страницами без перезагрузки, но так чтобы url страницы менялся?

Comment: [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History)

Comment: Что-то подобное я видел на blacknegative.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В HTML документе метод `history.pushState()` добавляет новое состояние в историю браузера

Метод **`pushState()`** принимает 3 параметра: `state`, `title` (который в данный момент игнорируется), `URL`. Давайте рассмотрим каждый параметр подробнее:

> **State** — JavaScript объект, который связан с новой записью в истории браузера, созданной при помощи `pushState()`. Всякий раз, когда пользователь перемещается на новое состояние истории браузера при помощи таких функций, как, например `history.back()` или `history.go()`, срабатывает событие popstate, а в объект event передаётся свойство `state`.
>
> **Title** — в данный момент Firefox игнорирует данный параметр. Тем не менее аргумент может передаваться. Передача пустой строки вместо `title` должна быть безопасной с учётом будущих изменений метода. В качестве альтернативы можно передавать `title` в объекте `state` и использовать его оттуда.
>
> **URL** — URL новой записи в истории браузера передаётся в этом аргументе. Обратите внимание, что браузер не будет пытаться загрузить данный URL после вызова `pushState()`, но эту попытку можно сделать позднее, например, после перезапуска браузера. Новый URL не обязательно должен быть абсолютным. Если он относительный, тогда он образуется от текущего URL.

```
var state = { 'page_id': 1, 'user_id': 5 };
var title = 'Hello World';
var url = 'hello-world.html';

history.pushState(state, title, url);
```